# Sampled data in R, how to replace randomly selected elements with 0

Tags: r, dataframe, repeat, random

I would like to repeat all rows in my data set with probability. Probability of repeating value in rows is depending on initial row. How can I determine for every elements in rows chance of being repeated?

Here is a little example data frame.

```
data <- data.frame(id = rep(c("01", "02", "03"),4), 
                    X1 = c(100,60,90,0,60,90,0,60,0,100,60,0),
                    X2 = c(0,60,90,0,60,0,0,0,90,0,0,90))
head(data)
  id  X1 X2
1 01 100  0
2 02  60 60
3 03  90 90
4 01   0  0
5 02  60 60
6 03  90  0
```

First column and column with value = 0 should be repeated. 
Numerical value in row should be repeated with chance 9/10. (I expect new data frame with repeated `id` column and 0-value elements)

a possible example output:

```
head(rep)
  id X1 X2
1 01  0  0
2 02 60 60
3 03 90  0
4 01  0  0
5 02  0 60
6 03 90  0
```

I have trouble with defining argument `prob=` in `sample()` for rows.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your question boils down to how to replace randomly selected elements of your data with 0. You can do this pretty simply with `runif`, in this case replacing each value with 0 with probability 0.1:

```
set.seed(144)
data[-1] <- sapply(data[-1], function(x) ifelse(runif(length(x)) < 0.1, 0, x))
data
#    id  X1 X2
# 1  01   0  0
# 2  02  60 60
# 3  03  90 90
# 4  01   0  0
# 5  02  60 60
# 6  03  90  0
# 7  01   0  0
# 8  02  60  0
# 9  03   0 90
# 10 01 100  0
# 11 02  60  0
# 12 03   0 90
```

With this random seed, the only change was in the first row of your example data.